# Jenkins. Как сделать чтобы каждый второй билд не запускал тесты?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Что нужно поменять/установить в настройках `джоба(item) Jenkins`, чтобы каждый второй билд не запускал тесты?

Comment: Слышал есть более простой способ, чем предложил уважаемый [Nofate](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate), а именно, использовать _переменную среды Jenkins_ - `BUILD_NUMBER`.
Если кто-то знает, пишите. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Можно поставить [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) - он позволяет задавать условие для выполнения отдельного шага сборки. В вашем случае таким условием является четность номера сборки.

По порядку:

1. Добавляете шаг *Conditional step (single)* в билд
2. В качестве условия *Run?* выбираете *Boolean condition*.
3. В качестве *Token* задаете выражение:

   ```
   ${GROOVY,script = "(Thread.currentThread().executable.number) %2 == 0"}
   ```
4. В качестве *Builder* указываете *Invoke Maven 3* и настраиваете ваш обычный maven-билд.
5. Повторяете шаги 1-4, но задаете условие для нечетности:

   ```
   ${GROOVY,script = "(Thread.currentThread().executable.number) %2 != 0"}
   ```

   и запускаете maven-билд с флагом `-DskipTests=true`

PS. У вас так же должны быть установлены [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) и [Token Macro Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Token+Macro+Plugin), в настройках Jenkins должен быть включен флаг *Groovy -> Allow token macro processing*

---

> Слышал есть более простой способ, а именно, использовать переменную среды Jenkins - `BUILD_NUMBER`.

По сути мы и так использовали `BUILD_NUMBER`, только не через переменные среды, а через API.

Если хотите без обойтись без groovy в голову приходят два варианта:

- **Вариант 2.** Можно взять *EnvInject Plugin* и перед сборкой инжектить в переменную, скажем `$RUN_TESTS`, значение `$(($BUILD_NUMBER % 2))`, что будет давать нам либо `1` либо `0`. А в переменную `$DONT_RUN_TESTS` соответственно противоположное значение: `$((1 - $BUILD_NUMBER % 2))`.

  Но это не избавит нас от *Conditional BuildStep Plugin*. Просто *Token*-ы поменяются на `${ENV,var='RUN_TESTS'}` и `${ENV,var='DONT_RUN_TESTS'}`

  *Conditional BuildStep Plugin* вообще всеядный и в качестве `true` рассматривает значения `1`, `y`, `yes`, `t`, `true`, `on`, `run`.
- **Вариант 3.** Другой вариант - настроить в самом `pom.xml` файле проекта средствами maven-а профиль в котором будут глушиться тесты. Пусть он называется `no-tests`. Теперь все тем же EnvInject-ом заинжектим переменную окружения, например `$MVN_PROFILE`, которая для четных билдов пустая, а для нечетных - содержит значение `-P no-tests`, то есть `$MVN_PROFILE` должна содержат результат вычисления:

  ```
  $(if [[ $(($BUILD_NUMBER  % 2)) -eq 0 ]]; then echo '-P no-tests'; fi )
  ```

Comment: Работает! 
Большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!

Для чего нужен плагін [Token Macro Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Token+Macro+Plugin)? Просто я его не ставил и всё равно работает))

Если у Вас будет возможность, пожалуйста, скиньте ссылки на материалы по данному вопросу. Хотелось б разобраться.

Comment: @Giovanni, *Token Macro Plugin* позволяет одним плагинам  регистрировать обработчики выражений типа `${GROOVY,script ... `, а другим - использовать эти выражения. Этот плагин мог быть уже установлен с чем-то другим как зависимость.

Comment: @Giovanni, По дженкинсу я не видел исчерпывающих руководств. Полагаюсь на список плагинов и собственные эксперименты. Есть парка книг, но они довольно слабые и годятся разве что для введения в предмет: *Jenkins: The Definitive Guide* и *Jenkins Continuous Integration Cookbook*

Comment: Вы правы, действительно плагін _Token Macro Plugin_ уже установлен. 
Еще раз спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Не делать тесты - опасная практика )

Comment: Да, пожалуй **Вариант 1** самый подходящий))
Только я немного сменил в нем заданное выражение *Token*,
*с*:
`${GROOVY,script = "(Thread.currentThread().executable.number) %2 == 0"}`
*на*:
`${GROOVY,script = "(${BUILD_NUMBER}) %2 == 0"}`
Но это не меняет суть! Еще раз благодарю)